# Почему исчезает символ \ при вводе управляющей последовательности через командную строку?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    const char *str = argv[1];
    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

На вход программы поступает некоторая строка как аргумент командной строки.

Пример запуска: ./programm ABC\tDEF

Ожидается, что в str будет содержаться строка "ABC\tDEF", однако вместо этого в ней содержится строка ABCtDEF
Почему опускается символ '\'?
При запуске ./programm "ABC\tDEF" выдается желаемый результат

Comment: Так работает интерпретатор командной строки, который Вы используете. Взятие подобных строк в кавычки - нормальная практика

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за разъяснение